# Dynamically Added Combo Box Item Object Doesn't Raise Change Notification

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, runtime

I have a custom type `ObservableCollection` that is bound to a ComboBox Item Source through a Data Template, which contains for each item an Ellipse with fill color depending on item text, and I have another tab where I can change the item color.
The problem is that when I add a new item at run time with a specific color, the item will be added normally, but when I try to change the color for the new item, it will not be changed in the `ObservableCollection` mentioned above.

I have noticed that the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` variable (PropertyChanged) is always null for the newly added ComboBox Items while the original items are not null therefore the item object is not raising the notification to the WPF UI as below:

```cs
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) //this handler is always null for the new added Items
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your observation may or may not be useful, but you are lacking the code to demonstrate the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: show how you add the items

Answer (score 0):

Item must have INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation for updating itself in your combobox.

Do you sure what your combobox items (collection items) were updated correctly?